# Order email template override in magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates

Am trying to override the sales order email and I did that override but I have doubt in code, In that email template they called variable like

```
{{var payment_html|raw}}
```

in payment methods, I want to know in which file this variable is calling please tell me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find `payment_html` in: [`\Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\OrderSender::prepareTemplate()`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/Model/Order/Email/Sender/OrderSender.php#L123)